# Hide bq command line `query` output

Tags: python, google-bigquery, analytics

I am using the bq command line tool to execute queries from a remote machine and then send out to specific tables. `bq query` displays the query output everytime. what is the flag to suppress/hide output from `bq query` command?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `-n=0` option to `bq query`. Here is an example with and without this option:

```
$ bq query --use_legacy_sql=false "SELECT x FROM UNNEST([1, 2, 3]) AS x;"
Waiting on <job id> ... (0s) Current status: DONE   
+---+
| x |
+---+
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
+---+
$ bq query -n=0 --use_legacy_sql=false "SELECT x FROM UNNEST([1, 2, 3]) AS x;"
Waiting on <job id> ... (0s) Current status: DONE
```

Comment: `-n=0` gave `--max_rows==0: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '=0'` for me, but `-n 0` worked

Answer (score 0):

FYI for the documentation.

[bq command-line tool reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference)

- [bq query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_query)

```
--max_rows=MAX_ROWS or -n=MAX_ROWS
An integer specifying the number of rows to return in the query results. The default value is 100.
```

Other command which output rows e.g. `head` has the same option.